# Operations on Classes

Tags: set-theory

I am wondering about size issues in mathematics.

The most important questions I have are:

> Is it possible to take the hom-class between two classes?

> What things can we do with sets that we cannot do with classes?

A more open-ended question is:

> Also, is it possible to form increasingly large structures, like "2-Classes", one of which would be able to contain all classes?

Here I am asking for a consistent way of making sense of $2$-classes, and what reasonable seeming axioms have to be discluded to avoid a Russel-like pardox. This is a pretty open ended question.

The idea is that there are $N$ types of objects called $n$-classes, $0 \leq n < N$, where:

1. $n$-classes satisfy extensionality.
2. We can form an $n$-class $\text{Hom}(X, Y)$ for an $n$-class $X$ and an $n$-class $Y$.
3. We can form an $n$-class $X \cup Y$ for $n$-classes $X$ and $Y$.
4. An $n-1$-class is an $n$-class.
5. There is an $n$-class consisting of all $n-1$-classes
6. We can do restricted comprehension of $n$-classes.
7. $n$-classes satisfy replacement.
8. $0$-classes satisfy ZF.

The purpose of the construction is so that there is no "$n$-class of all $n$-classes", while on the other hand we still have many tools available to manipulate the $n$-classes so as to make bigger ones.

Comment: Possible in what context? Is it possible to collect infinitely many numbers into a set? In $\sf ZF-Inf+\lnot Inf$, no; in $\sf ZF$ yes. Is it possible to collect all subsets of $\Bbb N$ into a single set? In $\sf ZFC-Power+\text{every set is countable}$, no, in $\sf ZF$, yes. Do you see where I'm going with this?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm just interested in consistency here. I'll add some details in case it's too open-ended.

Comment: It sounds like you’re reinventing Grothendieck universes.